# Loading wrong resources in SharePoint user control

Tags: localization, sharepoint-2010, ascx

We have a customer with a SharePoint 2010 server and variations set up for en-US and fr-CA. The specified language is English and French, respectively. When a French-Canadian employee goes on a page in the fr-CA variation, all the controls defined in the master page are localized in French correctly, even one of our own controls injected by a delegate control.

The main web part on the page loads our own container control, consisting of some minor markup and an UpdatePanel. Now everything on this control gets localized incorrectly in English. There is some additional content, which get loaded by aspx pages, and this content gets localized correctly.

I am not able to reproduce this issue in my local development SharePoint, so I am quite in the dark here. The controls are basically loaded via `Page.LoadControl` with a path like `/_controltemplates/Container.ascx`. Do I need the `~` in front of the path? What does that do exactly? Also, would that explain why this is only occurring in the customer's SharePoint and not in my local one?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the uls log for failing resource look ups, could be some not up-to-date resource files on the server where you are experience the missing localization, hence the reason why you can't reproduce it.